# What does "the lesser lights" in the below context mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm reading a book "No-No Boy" by John Okada and there is a phrase that I'm not sure I understand correctly.
Does "the lesser lights" mean something like "the least dangerous people"?

Below is a fragment from the book with the phrase (bolded by me):

> First, the real Japanese-Japanese were rounded up. These real Japanese-Japanese were Japanese nationals who had the misfortune to be diplomats and bussinessmen and visitng professors. They were put on a boat and sent back to Japan. Then the alien Japanese, the ones who had been in America for two, three, or even four decades, were screened, and those found to be too actively Japanese were transported to the hinterlands and put in a camp. The security screen was sifted once more and, this time, **the lesser lights** were similarly plucked and deposited. An old man, too old, too feeble, and too scared, was caught in the net.

Comment: The people with less reason to be feared by the authorities than the other two categories.

Comment: Compare 'leading lights' -the most important or significant.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. A century ago, [***lesser lights*** was actually more common than ***leading lights***,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+lesser+lights%2Cthe+leading+lights&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) but the situation has completely reversed since then. So you probably shouldn't *copy* the cited usage, because even some *native* speakers today wouldn't be familiar with it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Though most of the earlier instance of _lesser lights_ seem to mean the stars (in comparison with the sun and moon).

Comment: @KateBunting: Sounds plausible. But it seems a little odd to use "leading / lesser lights" to reference people judged to be more or less "actively Japanese", so I stand by my advice not to copy the usage.

Comment: lesser lights are Japanese people of less importance: Japanese-Japanese, alien Japanese, and then the ones who were less important.

Comment: @Lambie: *Normally*, such a figurative usage would refer to "leading / lesser lights" *relative to the society within which they live* - people who were more or less "famous" within American society as a whole. But I suspect that in the cited context it just means people of more or less interest to the U.S. Department of Homeland Security, not the general public.

Comment: Thank you all very much!